# Docker-compose on wsl cannot start terminator in container

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, wsl-2

Good day to everyone,

I seem to have a problem with docker-compose and wsl2 on windows 10.
I am running docker on ubuntu 20.04 in wsl2 on windows 10. For some reason if I run the docker image with this command:

```
sudo docker run --rm -it --network host -e DISPLAY -v ${HOME}/.config/terminator:/home/user1/.config/terminator -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -v ${PWD}/.bashrc_local:/home/user1/.bashrc_local -e QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 --privileged hsp/ros2-bench-test:r1Sim2
```

Bash runs as expected and I can start terminator and other GUI based software.

But if I use docker-compose I get this error:

```
sudo docker-compose up
Creating network "docker_compose_default" with the default driver
Creating terminator                       ... done
Creating docker_compose_yarp-ros2-image_1 ... done
Attaching to terminator, docker_compose_yarp-ros2-image_1
terminator         | 
terminator         | (terminator:20724): dbind-WARNING **: 07:58:24.948: Couldn't register with accessibility bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
terminator         | Unable to connect to DBUS Server, proceeding as standalone
terminator         | 
terminator         | ** (terminator:20724): WARNING **: 07:58:25.089: Binding '<Control><Alt>a' failed!
terminator         | Unable to bind hide_window key, another instance/window has it.
terminator         | Traceback (most recent call last):
terminator         |   File "/usr/bin/terminator", line 133, in <module>
terminator         |     TERMINATOR.layout_done()
terminator         |   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/terminatorlib/terminator.py", line 329, in layout_done
terminator         |     terminal.spawn_child()
terminator         |   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/terminatorlib/terminal.py", line 1500, in spawn_child
terminator         |     result,  self.pid = self.vte.spawn_sync(Vte.PtyFlags.DEFAULT,
terminator         | gi.repository.GLib.GError: g-io-error-quark: Failed to execute child process “/bin/bash”: Failed to fdwalk: Operation not permitted (14)
terminator exited with code 1
docker_compose_yarp-ros2-image_1 exited with code 0
```

The docker-compose is the following:

```
version: "3.7"

x-base: &base
  image: hsp/ros2-bench-test:r1Sim2
  environment:
    - DISPLAY=${DISPLAY}
    - XAUTHORITY=/home/user1/.Xauthority
    - QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1
    - LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=0
    - YARP_COLORED_OUTPUT=1
  volumes:
    - "/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw"
    - "/etc/hosts:/etc/hosts"
    - "/home/elandini/.gitconfig:/home/user1/.gitconfig"
    - ".bashrc_local:/home/user1/.bashrc_local"
    - "/home/elandini/.config/terminator:/home/user1/.config/terminator"
  network_mode: host
  ipc: host
  pid: host
  security_opt:
    - apparmor:unconfined


services:

# Images
  yarp-ros2-image:
    image: hsp/ros2-bench-test:r1Sim2
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: ros2CtrlDefault
      context: .


  terminator:
    <<: *base
    container_name: terminator
    command: terminator -g /home/user1/.config/terminator/config
```

I cannot see the error in the docker-compose.yaml file, but I am quite new to docker-compose and so it may be really trivial.

**EDIT**

Thanks to [ste93](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15824010/ste93) for the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72866461/3110576). With `privileged: true` everything works.

Does anybody knows a way to avoid giving privileges to the container and still make this work?

Answer (score 1):

If you put `privileged: true` in the docker compose it should work.